# How to improve NSTableView performance?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I am using a datasource and a delegate for the tableview. The responsive seems to be acceptable for 500-800 rows. Anything above 1500 rows the response time is about 7-10 seconds and the scrolling becomes choppy too.

Just to give the broader context, there is a list of database tables. When one of these is selected, the table data is shown. So essentially I am dynamically removing and adding columns to the tableview.

First I remove the columns after setting the delegate for the tableview to nil (otherwise the tableview will refresh and call the delegate). A database query is made after this asking for the column data. Then I add the columns based on the database query result: anywhere from two to thirty columns. After that [tableView reload] is called. The database results are in a NSMutableArray, which, in the delegate is set as NSArray. The column values are in NSDictionary.

```
-(NSView*)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

NSDictionary* rowData = [_tableData objectAtIndex:row];
NSString* identifier = [tableColumn identifier];

NSTableCellView* result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"myCellView" owner:self];
if (result == nil) {
    //result = _myTableCellView; commented out because result would be nil without
    // an IBOutlet in the windowcontroller which is not the case now.
    NSLog(@"result in nil");
    //[[result textField] setStringValue:[rowData objectForKey:identifier]];
}
else {
    [[result textField] setStringValue:[rowData objectForKey:identifier]];
}

// NSLog(@"result text field: %@", [[result textField] stringValue]);
return result;

}
```

I have run the code through Instrument's Timer profiler. It seems that 95% of the time is spend in "unarchiving" the view in makeViewWithIdentifier. The database access is extremely fast—it is a local postgres instance. So that is not a bottleneck. I wonder if I should start thinking about some form of paginating data in the table view. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is it faster if you create those cells to NSArray and in `viewForTableColumn` just return object at right index of array instead making cell every time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013990/nstableviews-viewfortablecolumnrow-called-for-more-rows-than-expected-in-mave After 6 years here is some answer