# NSTableview View Based Scrolling Performance

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, scroll, nstableview

I am fairly new to **OS X Cocoa** programming but have decided to give it a go with the new Swift language.

I have an `NSTableView` with 1500 rows (will be more) and 7 columns. There is one checkbox column and the rest are text fields, one with a date formate and one a currency formatter. I first set this up as cell based. Scrolling was buttery smooth (I even did a test adding 1 million rows, still smooth). This was under mavericks.

I then upgraded to **Yosemite**, scrolling performance significantly degraded. Enabling Core animation layer checkbox on the table view improved this but was still worse than in mavericks.

During my reading trying to improve scroll performance in Yosemite I came across "View-Based" NSTableViews. From the documentation it said cell based table views should generally not be used and are only supported for legacy projects.

I therefore converted my table to a View based table view. Sample simple concept, nothing complicated. The scrolling performance is absolutely terrible. If you scroll very slow it is smooth enough but as soon as you start to scroll faster its like it hasn't buffered enough and it starts stuttering and jerking. Also when the `NSTableview` is populated, focusing and defocusing the window takes a second or more (I tried it in mavericks again and this was not present, scrolling was also a little better, but still nowhere near cell based).

Are view based `NSTableviews` always bad for scrolling performance? If so why do apple recommend using them over cell based `NSTableviews`.

Also some applications like safari and Reeder2 have buttery smooth scrolling even in Yosemite. How do they achieve this?

Am I missing something or is the performance of OS X just going to hell with each new thing? I.e

> Mavericks > Yosemite
>
> Cell-Based > View-Based
>
> Old > New

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately not. I have stopped development and will try again at next version of OS X before calling it quits.

Comment: Did you report a bug on radar? Not that Apple would care about, but just out of curiosity. I feel really, really pissed by Apple. As long as I just use TextFields in my large table it's smooth, but once I add just a Colorbox/TextField view it starts eating all CPU while scrolling. Yosemite sucks >:-(

Comment: @Gavin did you find a solution? I hit the same issue even in macOS 10.11 and 10.12. View-based table views are extremely slow if there are 1000+ rows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013990/nstableviews-viewfortablecolumnrow-called-for-more-rows-than-expected-in-mave After 5 years here is some answer

Answer (score 4):

According to Apple, OSX never enable QuartzCore by default (as iOS, instead, do). So, you need to:

- link against QuartzCore.framework your project under Build Settings pane.
- enable CoreAnimation Layer (under View Effects Inspector on IB) for your main window (if possible, otherwise be sure to enable it on the container view that give you poor performances).

Quoting Apple docs:

> In iOS apps, Core Animation is always enabled and every view is backed
>   by a layer. In OS X, apps must explicitly enable Core Animation
>   support by doing the following:
>
> Link against the QuartzCore framework. (iOS apps must link against
>   this framework only if they use Core Animation interfaces explicitly.)
>   Enable layer support for one or more of your NSView objects by doing
>   one of the following:
>
> In your nib files, use the View Effects inspector to enable layer
>   support for your views. The inspector displays checkboxes for the
>   selected view and its subviews. It is recommended that you enable
>   layer support in the content view of your window whenever possible.
>   For views you create programmatically, call the view’s setWantsLayer:
>   method and pass a value of YES to indicate that the view should use
>   layers. Enabling layer support in one of the preceding ways creates a
>   layer-backed view. With a layer-backed view, the system takes
>   responsibility for creating the underlying layer object and for
>   keeping that layer updated. In OS X, it is also possible to create a
>   layer-hosting view, whereby your app actually creates and manages the
>   underlying layer object. (You cannot create layer-hosting views in
>   iOS.) For more information on how to create a layer-hosting view, see
>   “Layer Hosting Lets You Change the Layer Object in OS X.”

More on: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html

Answer (score 3):

I recently found myself in a very similar situation, having a cell based `NSOutlineView` that was blazing fast pre-Yosemite and almost crawled to a halt after upgrading to Yosemite.

In my experience, enabling layer-backing on the table view itself is not enough, you also have to enable it for the `NSScrollView` that contains your table view and it's `NSClipView`.

After making those changes my table view was up to speed again but experiencing some strange visual artifacts. Those might or might not be relevant in your situation since you're not using an source list `NSOutlineView` that uses the new vibrancy/transparency stuff in Yosemite.

In any case, those "effects" went away as soon as I converted to a view based table.

Comment: I did actually have NSOutlineview too, and was seeing the visual artefacts you speak of. They also went away when using View based. View based seems to lag terribly after you scroll out of the "Buffered" zone. which seems to be around 500 items or so.

Comment: Also I now have a problem that when the table is full (can see about 30 entries on screen), the window takes about 1 second to activate focus and deactivate focus. Do you also have this, Cant figure out what the cause is, although completely disabling layer backed fixes it :S

Comment: I haven't seen the focus issues you're describing but several other strange issues that started with Yosemite. Have you tried to enable layer-backing on the scroll- and clip-view yet?

Comment: Another thing to try out (once you have enabled layer-backing for the scroll- and clip-view) is to overwrite `canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer` in your `NSTableRowView`s to return YES which effectively tells the rows to draw into the table view's layer instead of creating a separate layer for each row. Here's some more info on that: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSView/canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer

Comment: I had the view which the tableview is in using layer backed so it is therefore also using it. (although I enabled explicitly for scroll an clip view to but no improvement) Interestingly the canDrawSubViewsIntoLayer did have a noticeable impact. Firstly it reduced the focussing lag. Not perfect, but better. Secondly it seemed to reduce the massive stutter lag as you scroll far from the current area quickly. However it actually made the frame rate lower when scrolling only very locally, and it made the add remove animations super laggy. like 3fps.

Comment: Im thinking the focus lag is caused by the window redrawing all its layers for some reason when it gets focused (more layers, more lag), and the scroll lag seems like it hasn't buffered enough beyond the current scroll region. Is it possible to change the buffering size for scroll views?, or prevent redrawing on window focus?

Comment: Regarding the buffering of scroll views: You might want to watch the WWDC 2013 session "Optimizing Drawing and Scrolling on OS X" which also goes in to depth about customizing overdraw. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/

Comment: Regarding layer-backing: I've seen some very strange behavior when layer-backing is not done exactly the way Apple intended it in scroll views. You might want to try turning on layer-backing only(!) for the scroll view and the contained clip view. That is, NOT the view containing the scroll view and NOT the table view within the clip view.

Answer (score 0):

Recently they have introduced the concept called "Reuse queues", where in only the rows which are currently visible are actually there in the table. The rows which go out of the clip, while scrolling are replaced by the newly introduced rows. This was introduced for performance enhancements. But considering million x 7 views, I suppose there might be a lot of CPU cycles wasted in reuse queue.
Also cells are light weight as compared to views.

---

If possible you can consider, restructuring the single tableview to multiple tableviews. Practically human being needs to view the data with atleast some simple predicate in their mind. For example, in an organization you might want to view

1. All manager details
2. All employees having salary greater than x
3. All female employees

instead of viewing all employee details at a time.
Thus initializing a table view, only with the required information would enhance both, the performance and UX.

Comment: Yeah, it's time to do paging on long lists on desktop apps too. I also do Gtk Linux and Windows GUI clients and they are all wasting lots of resources when used with many items and i mean lots like in 100s of Megabytes of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem. I'm also new to Swift and Apple development in general. My project was working well until I started adding a 1000 or more rows.

After some playing around, I've narrowed the issue down to the way that my dictionary based data source is being accessed. This might point you in the right direction.

```
 func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject? {...

 return myDictionary.values.array[row] //-- this makes access very slow, jerky with pauses

return myDictionary[someKey] //-- this makes access a lot faster, smooth and slick
```

Looks like my data source needs some re-work. It still hasn't been tested with large quantities of data, but at the outset seems to make a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply turn off the "Draws Background" on the text cell (or the group cell)

[image]