# NSViewController slow to register mouse events?

Tags: swift, macos

I've been working on a small image uploading menubar app for OS X. I've created custom `NSView` subclass for the uploaded items.

Here's what it looks like by default:

[image: Ravioli - not hovered]

Mouse events are handled by the view's `NSViewController` in the following way:

```
import Cocoa

class MenuItemController: NSViewController {

    private var trackingArea: NSTrackingArea?

    override func mouseEntered(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        if let v = self.view as? MenuItemView {
            v.shouldHighlight = true
            v.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }

    override func mouseExited(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        if let v = self.view as? MenuItemView {
            v.shouldHighlight = false
            v.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if (trackingArea == nil) {
            trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: self.view.bounds, options: [.ActiveAlways, .MouseEnteredAndExited], owner: self, userInfo: nil)
            self.view.addTrackingArea(trackingArea!)
        }

        /* rest of the code... */
    }

}
```

It works fine until I move my cursor fast over the items. It seems like the `mouseExited()` event is not called, and the view remains with a blue background (mouse is actually on the Quit button):

[image: Ravioli bug]

I also tried moving the mouse handling into the `NSView`, but with same results. I appreciate any input! Thanks!

Comment: This sounds very similar to other slow OSX performance issues where enabling Core Animation improves performance. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696644/nstableview-view-based-scrolling-performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, Apple has had bugs in this area.

Assuming you update your tracking area according to apple docs,
adding this additional fix might fix your problem... it fixes it for me in many cases.
I verify in mouseMoved / mouseEntered routine that the mouse cursor is still within my views frame, and if not, call mouseExited: myself.

```
- (void) adjustTrackingArea
{   
   if ( trackingArea )
   {
      [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
      [trackingArea release];
   }

   // determine the tracking options
   NSTrackingAreaOptions trackingOptions = // NSTrackingEnabledDuringMouseDrag | // don't track during drag
   NSTrackingMouseMoved |
   NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited |
   //NSTrackingActiveInActiveApp | NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow | NSTrackingActiveWhenFirstResponder |
   NSTrackingActiveAlways;
   NSRect theRect = [self visibleRect];
   trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc]
                   initWithRect: theRect
                   options: trackingOptions
                   owner: self
                   userInfo: nil];
   [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}


- (void)resetCursorRects
{
   [self adjustTrackingArea];
}
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)ev
{
   [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
   // make sure current mouse cursor location remains under the mouse cursor
   NSPoint cursorPt = [self convertPoint:[[self window] mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream] fromView:NULL];

   // apple bug!!!
   //NSPoint cursorPt2 = [self convertPointFromBase:[ev locationInWindow]]; 
   //if ( cursorPt.x != cursorPt2.x )
   //   NSLog( @"hello old cursorPt" );
   NSRect r = [self frame];
   if ( cursorPt.x > NSMaxX( r ) || cursorPt.x < 0 )
   {
      [self mouseExited:ev];
      //cursorPt.x = [self convertPointFromBase:[ev locationInWindow]];
      //if ( cursorPt.x > NSMaxX( r ) || cursorPt.x < r.origin.x )
      return;
   }

   ... your custom stuff here ...
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
   if ( isTrackingCursor == NO )
      return;

   [[NSCursor arrowCursor] set];
   isTrackingCursor = NO;
   [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];   
}

- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
   [self mouseEntered:theEvent];
}
```

Comment: I was able to come up with a solution based on this answer. Thank you Keith!

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand whether you are installing an NSTrackingArea for the whole window (in this case menu) or for each item. If you are doing the latter, don't do it, or you will spend an endless time to correct the problems you are seeing. The way I handled this buggy behaviour is to create an NSTrackingArea for the whole window and I figure myself where the mouse is and handle the highlighting of each item myself. I know this is not ideal, but this was the only way I was able to solve it after knocking myself in the head for three days.

Comment: This is a good answer too... I use a similar method to implement a browser-like toolTip system at the bottom of my window.  (power users dislike pop-up style tooltips on GUIs that they use often)

Answer (score 0):

You can track which was the old active menuitem and set manage it accordingly, something like:

```
override func mouseEntered(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        if let v = self.view as? MenuItemView {
            lastEntered.shouldHighLight = false
            lastEntered.needsDisplay = true
            lastEntered = v;
            lastEntered.shouldHighLight = true
            lastEntered.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }
```

Thus you will ensure that at most one will be active.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is a good fix for moving the cursor over the elements, but if I move the mouse outside the window without entering anything else (or a native NSMenuItem), the problem remains. :/