# Why does NSTableView request too many rows?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I noticed my application was running a bit slowly during an NSTableView reload. On checking, I found that the tableView was asking for ~104 more rows than it needed. For example, if the table was currently showing rows 0-18, then during initial load and during reloads, it would ask for views for the rows 0-122. If I grow the window to, say, 22 rows, then it asks for 0-125. If I then scroll down three rows (now showing 3-24), then it asks for the additional 126-127 rows. This is true for both tables in my window.

I checked the frame sizes, and the NSTableView itself grows proportionately to the numberOfRows, which I think is correct behavior, although it should only ask for the visible rows anyways. The frames for its superview (NSClipView) and superview.superview (NSScrollView) are both right (height of ~420) for the displayed size in the window.

For background, the app loads data in the background, so the number of data rows grows after the program launches. The window is loaded from a NIB; I'm using autoresizing, not autolayout. There are hundreds of data rows in the table. The numberOfRows value is correct.

Any thoughts where to look for this?

Comment: The method `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` is called each time the table cell needs to be redisplayed, so it must be efficient. Nowhere in the documentation does it say that it only requests visible cells.

Comment: I understand, and the performance isn't not too bad, and I could certainly understand getting a couple extra rows, but is it really standard behavior for it to get over 100 rows when it's only displaying 7? Certainly isn't the case on iOS.

Comment: Well, looks like it is. I created a new test app with as simple an NSTableView as possible and found the same thing.

Comment: In fact, this is new behavior in Mavericks and later "Responsive Scrolling. See this answer for explanation and workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013990/nstableviews-viewfortablecolumnrow-called-for-more-rows-than-expected-in-mave

Comment: Hmm, looks like you're right. You'd like they'd mention that in the documentation somewhere...

Comment: Experiencing exactly this!! And in my case hurts performance cuz I'm loading images from the disk and downscaling them…