# NSTableView is very laggy while scrolling

Tags: macos, performance, swift, core-data, nstableview

In my OS X application, which uses `Core Data` my table view is very laggy while scrolling and I have only about 100+ rows there...I'm using Cocoa bindings with `NSArrayController` to show my data in table view.

I have only one Entity with 13 attributes, but still that table view/scroll view is very laggy.

Is there some common bug / bad coding what causes that behavior? My CPU-usage is around 85% while I'm scrolling.

Anybody have any ideas why is that? I'm using Xcode 7 released version.

UPDATE:

Instruments look like this (I used it first time):
[image]

Update 2: Im using NSVisualEffectView and overriding allowsVibrancy to return true so I'm getting table views alternative row colors to be like this as in my another project [Github- Debter](https://github.com/Prontto/Debter)

If I enable core animation layer for my view it helps a lot for scrolling, but my storyboard start do something weard stuff and I can't work well any UI-releated stuff anymore.

Comment: Using Xcode's Instruments tool, you can profile the running app to see where it's spending its time.

Comment: I updated my answer and posted screenshot from Instruments...Can you figure anything out from that?

Comment: You are using CALayers , what's your Mac Model

Comment: 15" Macbook Pro Retina, early 2013

Comment: If you are doing core data fetches to populate the table this could be the problem. Is this the case? Try using the core data tool from instruments.

Comment: I dont think that's the problem because if I dont use NSVisualEffectView my scrolling is just fine, even if I have +10k rows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013990/nstableviews-viewfortablecolumnrow-called-for-more-rows-than-expected-in-mave After 4 years here is some answer

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code of your `UITableView` `delegate` and `data source` it is pretty hard to know the exact problem.

Some bad habits are:

- Loading data from CoreData from any of the `UITableViewDataSource` methods or when the `UITableViewCell` is being rendered.
- Loading images on the main thread or loading images in the background without caching them on local storage.
- Doing complex operations (like image processing) on `tableViewCellForIndexPath` or other data source methods.

Some questions that might help you find the problem:

- Are you using a `NSFetchedResultsController`? If your data set is long (although you mention is not) it could increase performance.
- Have you checked the number of threads? If it is too high, you might want to use an `NSOperationQueue` to limit your background tasks.

Comment: My app is for OS X and I make one fetchrequest when view controller did load and store data my array and populate my table view from there.

When I'm not using NSVisualEffectView, my scrolling is just fine and everything works, but that visualeffectview causes propblems.

Comment: Apologies for all my `UIKit` classes :). Are you doing the visual effect on each table view row?  Maybe a good idea would be to embed the entire table view into a visual effect view, then use a flat color with opacity on the rows to create a zebra effect.

Comment: I have visual effect in my entire view. For now I have removed it because that laggy experience.